# How do I include taxo description in a View's no argument summary?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've got a view with an argument based on taxo terms that shows a summary list when no argument is present. Now I need the list of terms to include a description for each one. Clearly the logical way to get this is to include the taxo description under each term, but I don't see how to do this. Drupal 6, views 2.

I'd be willing to take a stab at writing a Views plugin to get this functionality, but I don't really know where to start. I do have some idea how to get the taxo description through code, but now how to integrate that into a Views no argument option. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Interesting that no one replied to this. I would have thought this was a common need.

Turns out the answer was not a plugin but another display. Using the Views Group By module (https://drupal.org/project/views_groupby - thanks Phase2!) I created a page with the summary links but also including the taxo description. Made the links bring up the other display, and all is well.